# React Typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') for weather app search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, weather-api

I am trying to create a weather app, I am currently stuck on the search bar. I'm working within a component named Inputs.tsx (stores my search bar and buttons to display different temps (F and C)

I was able to display the current location for the weather (right now it is London) but once I hit backspace in the div I immediately get the following error:

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I am aware that the value is set to the current default location, but how do I change that once I type another city in and how can I make it display within my App component?

**Inputs.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { GrLocation } from "react-icons/gr";
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";

function Inputs() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const weatherData = await getWeather();
      setWeather(weatherData);
      console.log(weatherData);
    }

    load();
  }, []);
  if (!weather) {
    return <p>loading</p>;
  }

  const handleSearch = () => {
    if (weather !== "") setWeather({ q: weather });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="search-container">
        <AiOutlineSearch onClick={handleSearch} />
        <input
          id="search-bar"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search.."
          value={weather.location.name}
          onChange={(e) => setWeather(e.currentTarget.value)}
        ></input>
        <GrLocation />
        <div className="temperature">
          <button name="metric" id="fahrenheit-button">
            &deg;F
          </button>
          <p>|</p>
          <button name="imperial" id="celcius-button">
            &deg;C
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

async function getWeather() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=462eaa5d277d46b0957222907232503&q=London&aqi=no"
  );

  return response.json();
}

export default Inputs;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../src/mag-glass.svg";
import "./App.css";

import Inputs from "./components/Inputs";
import TemperatureAndDetails from "./components/TemperatureAndDetails";
import TimeAndLocation from "./components/TimeAndLocation";

function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState<any>();



  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const weatherData = await getWeather();
      setWeather(weatherData);
      console.log(weatherData);
    }

    load();
  }, []);
  if (!weather) {
    return <p>loading</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
      <Inputs />
      <TimeAndLocation />
      <h1>Weather in {weather.location.name}</h1>
      <h1 id="temp-display">{weather.current.temp_f}&deg;F</h1>
      <TemperatureAndDetails />
      <h1>Feels Like: {weather.current.feelslike_f}&deg;F</h1>
      <h1>Humidity: {weather.current.humidity}%</h1>
      <h1>Wind Speed: {weather.current.gust_mph} mph</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

async function getWeather() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=462eaa5d277d46b0957222907232503&q=London&aqi=no"
  );

  return response.json();
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You already have condition for `!weather` to show *Loading* so that's fine, however tell me what does `console.log('weather:', weather)` prints to the console?

Comment: I get the following error: VM80:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: weather is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (localhost/:1:25), <anonymous>:1:25)
    at <anonymous>:1:25

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining (?.) to handle the case when weather.location is undefined:

```
value={weather?.location?.name}
```

This will fix the issue for Inputs.

Initialize the weather state with an empty object instead of undefined:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState<any>({});
```

In both cases, you should also update the handleSearch() function to properly set the weather state with the search query, instead of trying to set it directly to an object with a q property:

```
const handleSearch = () => {
  if (weather.location.name !== '') {
    setWeather({ location: { name: weather.location.name } });
  }
};
```

Comment: I added the first part to value in Inputs, then I changed my use state within Inputs, then the handleSearch, but for some reason I am still getting the same error and I'm not sure why because "name" is "London" when I console.log(weatherData)

Comment: it says that the error is occuring at handleSearch

Comment: @Dilek Turns out your error is happening at `Inputs.tsx` and the `App.tsx` is not relevant to this issue.

It makes no sense that you'd wanna update an object `weather` with a value from the `input` what are you trying to achieve in here? Your value `value=weather.location.name}` is trying to access an object and then `onChange` is changing this object into a string? And your `AiOutlineSearch` receives a `handleSearch` that only serves to break your `Inputs` component. What is even your goal in here? You just dumped a bunch of code and everything contradicts the previous code you've written.

Comment: What purpose does the `input` of `value={weather.location.name} onChange={(e) => setWeather(e.currentTarget.value)}`serves? It's not making a new request if the user writes a new value. Instead put it in a `<p> Showing weather for: {weather?.location?.name} </p>`

Comment: What's this `const handleSearch = () => {if (weather !== "") setWeather({ q: weather });};` supposed to achieve? `undefined` and Objects are always `!== ''` = *not an empty string* - all of a sudden you are making a function that will make your `weather` state turn into a `weather.q.weather.location.name` why is that? You are trying to pass a `value={weather.location.name}` to your `input`, so why do you need a function to break this structure of accessibility?

Answer (score 0):

Just use ternary operator where you drill into `weather` to deal with situation when `weather` is null:
{weather ? weather.location.name : ''}